# Adding Auto scaling and load balancing for Sidekiq Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I have deployed an application on EC2 instance. My web app is running on one instance and for background processing I used the sidekiq and the sidekiq is running on another EC2 instance. Now there is lots of background processing involved in my application, now I want to add load balancer and auto scaling to my Sidekiq application. The autoscaling should work as follows: 'If the requests enqueued is greater than 5000, launch a new sidekiq server. If the load of first sidekq server decreases, then shut the second server and move the jobs of second server into the first'.

I don't have an idea about how to add autoscaling for sidekiq server and to add the required configurations. I want detailed information about this.

Answer (score 0):

To increase/decrease the servers on autoscaling group, you can do that based on amazon cloudwatch metrics related to AWS Elastic Load Balancing. See [Elastic Load Balancing Dimensions and Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html). So, in that link, you can see that there are metrics by name RequestCount, SurgeQueueLength and SpilloverCount. You can select one of them based on yor specific need to be used in your AWS autoscaling configuration.

[AWS AutoScaling Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-dg.pdf) gives detail information of how this can be done. [AWS ELB Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-dg.pdf) gives detailed information about how to configure Elastic Load Balancer. [AWS CloudWatch Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/acw-dg.pdf) gives detailed information about CloudWatch. I think based on my answer above and going through the documents, if you still have more questions, raise a specific issue.